# Superset-UI: Trouble Obtaining Guest Token for Dashboard Embedding – CSRF Token Issue

Tags: reactjs, flask, apache-superset

I'm working on embedding a Superset dashboard into my React app using superset-ui/embedded-sdk. In my React component, I'm trying to fetch a guest token to use with the Superset SDK. Here's my simplified JSX component:

```
// SupersetDashboard.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { embedDashboard } from '@superset-ui/embedded-sdk';

const SupersetDashboard = () => {
  const [guestToken, setGuestToken] = useState('');
  const [embedUrl, setEmbedUrl] = useState('');
  const dashboardId = '06e1a493-5c79-46f5-add3-9b7c980bf5b4';

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch a guest token from your backend (if applicable)
    // ...
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (guestToken) {
      setEmbedUrl(embedDashboard({
        host: 'http://localhost:8099',
        id: dashboardId,
        token: guestToken,
      }));
    }
  }, [guestToken]);

  return (
    <div>
      {embedUrl && <iframe src={embedUrl} width="100%" height="600" />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SupersetDashboard;
```

I'm encountering an issue while trying to obtain the guest token. Here's what I've done:

> Sent a POST request to localhost:8099/api/v1/security/login to get an access token.
> Used the access token in the Authorization header for a POST request to localhost:8099/api/v1/security/guest_token/.
> However, I'm receiving the following error:

`{ "errors": [ { "message": "400 Bad Request: The CSRF token is missing.", "error_type": "GENERIC_BACKEND_ERROR", "level": "error", "extra": { "issue_codes": [ { "code": 1011, "message": "Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error." } ] } } ] }`

I attempted to fetch the CSRF token by sending a GET request to localhost:8099/superset/csrf_token/, but I received HTML syntax for a 404 error page.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully obtain the guest token?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Making two changes in config.py worked for me.

1. `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False`
2. `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False`